# Best practice way to use form elements

Tags: javascript

When i use my form elements I start by doing this:

```
var form_elements = document.bookmark.elements;  // line 1
```

From there I use them as such

```
form_elements.url
form_elements.title
```

I know it's not good to access the DOM too much if you have to but I also know it's not good to have excess variables.  So that I could eliminate line 1 and just use

```
document.bookmark.elements.url
document.bookmark.elements.title
```

but then I wonder if I'm hitting the DOM on each line.

Which was is best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you learn about "I also know it's not good to have excess variables" ?

Comment: It's not an excess variable if you are going to use it more than once. But what is `document.bookmark` supposed to do? It's not any standard property.

Comment: You should not access the form this way. If one day an environment intruduces a property with this name it'll shadow the DOM Element and your application will break. Use `getElementById` or similar standardized DOM Methods.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. Property access on an object is likely no slower than variable look–up, which is just property access on the local variable object, so almost exactly the same thing.

Use variables to shorten the lookup chain (performance, maybe) or save typing (less likelihood of typos). Just use what suits.